# Are there less files for bootstrap's "Getting started" examples?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to adapt a few of [Bootstrap's getting started examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples) to build my own stuff upon them. As I am using LESS, I searched for the LESS source of theses examples' CSS files but I couldn't find any. The only [examples related files](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/docs/examples) I found on GitHub contained the compiled CSS.

Have I missed the LESS source files for the examples or don't they exist? I cannot beleave these professionals creating bootstrap are writing raw CSS with all their great tools at hand.

Comment: The examples have very little css that is not based on the default, so the answer is no. They include theme.less, which is more involved and creates this: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

Comment: Thanks! I hoped to learn how the justified-navigation examples' CSS was created the LESS way by some professionals to get started with LESS but I'll find different examples. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom CSS used in the Bootstrap example pages isn't compiled from Less, it's pure vanilla CSS. That's just how Mark Otto rolls, apparently. I would guess he does it that way because most(?) of Bootstrap's users don't use Less/SCSS. And the examples' custom styles are fairly simple, so Less wouldn't simplify them that much.